# SOAP Webservices

Tags: java, soap

I have a wsdl containing SAOP Header and SOAP Body. I generated client with eclipse and APACHE CXF and sent request. But request is failing saying Header is missed or invalid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import
            namespace="http://finservice.cl.com/Services/financier/Operational/Messages/Request"
            schemaLocation="financierRequest.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import
            namespace="http://finservice.cl.com/Services/financier/Operational/Messages/Response"
            schemaLocation="financierResponse6.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://finservice.cl.com/Services/Faults"
            schemaLocation="finserviceFaults.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.cl.com/Services/SOAPHeaders"
            schemaLocation="CLSoapHeaders.xsd"/>
        <xsd:import
            namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            schemaLocation="oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>


<message name="WS-Security-SOAPHeader">
    <part element="wssec:Security" name="Security"/>
</message>

<message name="CLSOAPHeader">
    <part element="hdr_ns:RequestContextHeader" name="requestHeader"/>
    <part element="hdr_ns:ProcessingNodesHeader" name="processingNodesHeader"/>
</message>


<message name="financierRequest">
    <part element="req_ns:financierRequestElement" name="financierRequestElement"/>
</message>


<message name="financierResponse">
    <part element="res_ns:financierResponseElement" name="financierResponseElement"/>
</message>


<message name="Fault_Exception">
    <part element="fault_ns:Fault" name="fault"/>
</message>


<portType name="finServicePortType">
    <operation name="getFinanciers">
        <input message="tns:financierRequest"/>
        <output message="tns:financierResponse"/>
        <fault message="tns:Fault_Exception" name="Fault_Exception"/>
    </operation>
</portType>


<binding name="finServiceBinding" type="tns:finServicePortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

    <operation name="getFinanciers">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body parts="financierRequestElement" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:CLSOAPHeader" part="requestHeader" use="literal"/>
            <!-- soap:header message="tns:CLSOAPHeader" part="processingNodesHeader" use="optional"/-->
            <soap:header message="tns:WS-Security-SOAPHeader" part="Security" use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:CLSOAPHeader" part="processingNodesHeader" use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:WS-Security-SOAPHeader" part="Security" use="literal"/>
        </output>
        <fault name="Fault_Exception">
            <soap:fault name="Fault_Exception" use="literal"/>
        </fault>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name="financierService_v4">
    <port binding="tns:finServiceBinding" name="finServicePort">
        <soap:address                     location="http://finservice.qtcorpCL.cl.com:20021/finservService"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Can any one guide me how to write client for this wsdl?
How to attach header for this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you test this wsdl in soapui? https://www.soapui.org/

I would suggest to first see what is the request and response structure of this web than may be you can use same request structure in your eclipse client. Soapui is very easy to use.

Comment: I sent request with SOAP UI and successfully got response.

Comment: Great! now i think you can use same structure of request into you generated client and hopefully it will work!

Answer (score 0):

To generate all the client artifacts, you would need to use `wsimport` and then read about SOAP clients... [Simple JAX-WS client](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)